# | versus || as inclusive OR in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm fairly used to using Ruby's or operator, `||`:

```
false || true
#=> true
false || false
#=> false
```

However I also noticed that you can use the single pipe, `|`:

```
false | true
#=> true
false | false
#=> false
```

Is there a reason, other than the fact that the single pipe `|` acts as a bitwise OR operator on Fixnum, and convention, to prefer `||` over `|`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`true` and `false` in ruby are instances of `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` respectively. The main difference is that `||` is a ruby operator, while `|` is a method of `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`.

As specified in the [documentation of `TrueClass`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.5/TrueClass.html#method-i-7C):

> Or—Returns true. As anObject is an argument to a method call, it is always evaluated; **there is no short-circuit evaluation** in this case.

This is used, e.g. in shorthand cast to boolean:

```
val = 5
puts (true & val)
#⇒ true
```

And, since the operand is *always evaluated*, in chains:

```
(true | myFunc(...)) && ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you mean to use `|` instead of `&` in your example however?

Comment: You are welcome. No, `true | EVERYTHING` is always evaluated to `true`. I meant `true & 5` explicitly casts `5` to `boolean true`.